# Assigning value is slow

Tags: reactjs, select, input, center, rangeslider

I created a range slider with conditional rendering in React, I have a select input based on the value min max of the range slider will change, and the thumb for the range slider is misplaced if touched. The value of the first  event is getting assigned after the second event. I need to solve two issues,

1.The thumb of the slider should be in center after each change in select input

2.The values are assigned slowly

I am attaching my code below

```
   const [cost,setCost] =  useState();
    const [leads,setLeads] = useState();
    const [title,setTitle] = useState();
    const [min,setMin] = useState();
    const [max,setMax] = useState();
    const [range, setRange] = useState();
    const [low, setLow] = useState(false);
    const [high,setHigh] = useState(false);
    const [selected,setSelected] = useState(false);

    function handleChange(event){
      console.log(cost);
      setSelected(true);
        var category = event.target.value;
        setTitle(category);
        console.log(category);
        if(category === "Acrylic Bath"){
           setMin(85);
           setMax(415);
           setCost(250);
           setLeads("1-2");
        }else if(category === "Awinings"){
          setMin(85);
           setMax(165);
          setCost(120);
          setLeads("2-3");
        }else if(category === "Cabinet Refacing"){
          setMin(185);
           setMax(415);
          setCost(250);
          setLeads("1-2");
        }else if(category ==="Carpentry"){
          setMin(25);
           setMax(95);
          setCost(60);
          setLeads("1-2");
        }
      }
    
    function handleRange(event){
      event.persist();
        setCost(event.target.value);
        console.log(cost);
        if(title === "Acrylic Bath"){
          if(cost >= 226 && cost <= 325){
            setLeads("1-2");
            setLow(false);
            setHigh(false);
          }else if(cost >= 326 && cost <= 400){
            setLeads("2-3");
            setLow(false);
            setHigh(false);
          }
          else if(cost >= 200 && cost <= 225){
            setLeads("0-1");
            setLow(false);
            setHigh(false);
          }else if (cost < 200){
            setLow(true);
            setHigh(false);
          }else if(cost > 400){
            setLow(false);
            setHigh(true);
          }  
        }else if(title === "Awinings"){
          if(cost >= 105 && cost <= 114){
            setLeads("1-2");
            setLow(false);
            setHigh(false);
          }else if(cost >= 100 && cost <= 104){
            setLeads("0-1");
            setLow(false);
            setHigh(false);
          }else if(cost >= 116 && cost <= 127){
            setLeads("2-3");
            setLow(false);
            setHigh(false);
          }else if(cost >= 128 && cost <= 141){
            setLeads("3-4");
            setLow(false);
            setHigh(false);
          }else if(cost >= 142 && cost <= 150){
            setLeads("4-5");
            setLow(false);
            setHigh(false);
          }else if (cost < 100){
            setLow(true);
            setHigh(false);
          }else if(cost > 150){
            setLow(false);
            setHigh(true);
          }  
        }else if(title === "Cabinet Refacing"){
          if(cost >= 226 && cost <= 325){
            setLeads("1-2");
            setLow(false);
            setHigh(false);
          }else if(cost >= 326 && cost <= 400){
            setLeads("2-3");
            setLow(false);
            setHigh(false);
          }
          else if(cost >= 200 && cost <= 225){
            setLeads("0-1");
            setLow(false);
            setHigh(false);
          }else if (cost < 200){
            setLow(true);
            setHigh(false);
          }else if(cost > 400){
            setLow(false);
            setHigh(true);
          }  
        }else if(title === "Carpentry"){
          if(cost >= 50 && cost <= 70){
            setLeads("1-2");
            setLow(false);
            setHigh(false);
          }else if(cost >= 70 && cost <= 80){
            setLeads("2-3");
            setLow(false);
            setHigh(false);
          }
          else if(cost >= 40 && cost <= 49){
            setLeads("0-1");
            setLow(false);
            setHigh(false);
          }else if (cost < 40){
            setLow(true);
            setHigh(false);
          }else if(cost > 80){
            setLow(false);
            setHigh(true);
          }  
        }
      }
    

  return(
    <div className="calculator">
    <div className="container">
        <h1 className="calc-h">Price Calculator</h1>
        <p className="calc-p text-center">Title/Category</p>
        <select  name="category" onChange={handleChange} className="select" placeholder="Select One" id="category">
            <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Select One</option>
            <option value="Acrylic Bath">Acrylic Bath</option>
            <option value="Awinings">Awinings</option>
            <option value="Cabinet Refacing">Cabinet Refacing</option>
            <option value="Carpentry">Carpentry</option>
        </select>
        <p className="text-center calc-p">Set your lead price</p>
         {selected ? 
          <div>                  
        <input
        type="range"
        name="range"
        className="slider"
        min={min}
        max={max}
        Value={cost}
        onChange={handleRange}
        data-orientation="horizontal"
        step="1"
        />
         <br></br>
         <h4 className="text-center drag-h">${cost} per valid lead</h4>
         {high ?
          <p className="text-center drag-h">At this price you are overpaying</p>
         :
         <div>
         {low ?
          <p className="text-center drag-h">Price <span class="red">too low</span> to provide estimate</p>
          :
          <p className="text-center drag-h">At this price you can expect <span className="highlight">{leads} leads per day</span></p>
         }         
         </div>
         }
         </div>
         :
         <div>         
         <input
        type="range"
        name="range"
        className="slider"
        data-orientation="horizontal"
        disabled
        />
         <br></br>
          <h4 className="text-center drag-h">Drag to set your lead price</h4>
          </div>
         }

        <button className="sign-btn">SIGN UP</button>
        <br></br>
        <span className="span">Estimates are not a guarantee of performance, numbers based on a service area of approximately 300,000 homeowners.</span>
    </div>
   </div>

  );
}
```

I need the range slider thumb to be at the center

Answer (score 0):

about the second issue, I suggest using lodash.debounce to update value

```
    const handleChangeDebounce = useCallback(debounce(() => {
      // update the value here
    }, 300), [])
```

```
    <input
     type="range"
     name="range"
     className="slider"
     min={min}
     max={max}
     //Value={cost} // will not assign value here
     onChange={handleChangeDebounce}
     data-orientation="horizontal"
     step="1"
    />
```

the issue now is to set the default value of input:

```
    <input
     defaultValue={defaultInputValue}
     ...
    />
```

Comment: I tried debounce but the issue still remains, since the value of range slider and amount is determined by the same variable, the knob is misplaced